# How to iterate over objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array object as mentioned below;

```
var myArray=[{dateformat:"apr1", score:1},{dateformat:"apr2",score:2},{dateformat:"apr3",score:3}];
```

I would like to extract the values of dateformat into a separate array, e.g.:

```
var dateArray=["apr1","apr2","apr3"];
var score=[1,2,3];
```

I am using a `for` loop to extract the index but I'm not able to get the values.

Comment: *"but I'm not able to get the values"* ... show us the code. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service, the idea is to help you fix **your code** that isn't performing as expected

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` to iterate over the initial array objects and return the item you want.

```js
var myArray=[{dateformat:"apr1", score:1},{dateformat:"apr2",score:2},{dateformat:"apr3",score:3}];

var dateArray = myArray.map(function(obj){return obj.dateformat;}),
    score = myArray.map(function(obj){return obj.score});
    
console.log(dateArray);
console.log(score);
```

Answer (score 0):

If only you don't want to hard code the variables, you could use `Array#forEach` and `Object.keys` to store each unique key values inside e.g. array.

**Note**: It doesn't matter **how many** keys do you have in your objects, following solution will always return you the right output. Mind that you don't even have to initially declare new variables.

```js
var myArray = [{dateformat:"apr1", score:1},{dateformat:"apr2",score:2},{dateformat:"apr3",score:3}],
    obj = {};
    
    myArray.forEach(v => Object.keys(v).forEach(function(c) {
      (obj[c] || (obj[c] = [])).push(v[c]);
    }));
    
    console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the empty arrays, and use forEach with an argument of 'element' (which represents each object in the array) and push esch of the properties of each object into the required array.

```js
 var dateArray=[]; 
 var score=[];
 
 var myArray=[
   {dateformat:"apr1", score:1},
   {dateformat:"apr2",score:2},
   {dateformat:"apr3",score:3}
 ];
 

myArray.forEach(function(element) {
  dateArray.push(element.dateformat);
  score.push(element.score);
});

console.log(dateArray); //gives ["apr1","apr2","apr3"]
console.log(score); //gives ["1","2","3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer as a simple loop.

```
 var dateArray = new Array(myArray.length);
 for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
      var value = myArray[i];
      var dateValue = value.dateformat;
      dateArray[i] = dateValue;
 }
```

You can accomplish the same using the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
 var dateArray = myArray.map(function(value) { return value.dateformat; });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single loop approach of the given array and iterate the keys and push the values to the wanted arrays.

```js
var myArray = [{ dateformat: "apr1", score: 1 }, { dateformat: "apr2", score: 2 }, { dateformat: "apr3", score: 3 }],
    dateArray = [],
    score = [];

myArray.forEach(function (target, keys) {
    return function(a) {
        keys.forEach(function(k, i) {
            target[i].push(a[k]);
        });
    };
}([dateArray, score], ['dateformat', 'score']));

console.log(dateArray);
console.log(score);
```

Comment: Why use `reduce`? Your step function takes the accumulator `r` and just returns it, i.e. all steps use the same accumulator (it's a constant within the loop). Why not use `forEach` instead?